Can decltype be used to name the class of a method?
Using -std=c++23, gcc accepts the following code while clang rejects it:
struct outer {
  struct {
    int x;
    inline int get_x() const;
  } inner;
};

inline int
decltype(outer::inner)::get_x() const
{
  return x;
}

Specifically, clang 18.1 complains:
nested.cc:9:25: error: 'decltype' cannot be used to name a declaration
    9 | decltype(outer::inner)::get_x() const
      | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^

That said, both compilers accept using a type alias, as in the following:
using inner_type = decltype(outer::inner);
inline int
inner_type::get_x() const
{
  return x;
}

Which (if either) compiler is right and why?  Is there any trick I can use to avoid creating a type alias for out-of-line method definitions of unnamed structures, or to make it work if the inner type is private?
Please note that unlike this question, my nested name specifier starts with a decltype, so this is not the same as asking why outer::decltype(outer::inner)::... is not valid (which I already understand).  Specifically, the answer to the previous question is "A decltype-specifier can never appear except at the beginning of a nested-name-specifier," which does not help to resolve the question of which compiler is correct in my case or what language in the standard makes it so.  (Or if anything, it suggests the opposite of the previous answer--that in my case gcc is correct and clang is incorrect.)
Note further that the answer to this question also does not help determine which compiler is correct (though it suggests both are wrong for older versions of C++).  I'm specifically asking about C++23, yet the cited language from [class.mfct] in the previous answer has been deleted in the C++23 standard.  C++23 does say (11.4.2/3):

Member functions of a local class shall be defined inline in their class definition, if they are defined at all.

However, I don't see how decltype(outer::inner) meets the definition of a local class, because it isn't defined inside a function.

FWIW MSVC also accepts the first version. But what not simply give the inner struct a name ?

Or actually define (implement) the function inline in the structure definition?

To avoid the type alias you can use inline int std::type_identity_t<decltype(outer::inner)>::get_x() const (Though I'm not sure if that's actually valid code or if the typedef was valid in the first place)

See also Defining unnamed class member functions? that shows the old wording.

decltype can't be used as any component of the qualified-id of a declarator-id per [expr.prim.id.qual]/2:

A nested-name-specifier is declarative if it is part of

[...]
a qualified-id that is the id-expression of a declarator-id, or
[...]

A declarative nested-name-specifier shall not have a decltype-specifier. [...]

This is different than the other answer linked in the question. The grammar doesn't permit a decltype-specifier in any position of a nested name specifier except as the first component, regardless of context, as that answer points out. However, the rule above also disallows the use as the first component in declarative contexts.

Thanks, so definitions count as a declarative use? From this it seems the code with a type alias is correct. What about the type_identity_t trick where the decltype is inside a template argument?

@user3188445 I am not 100% sure that the other variations are ok, but probably yes.

@user3188445 • Here's another fun case, long{5} works, however long long{5} does not.  But... std::type_identity_t<long long>{5} to the rescue!  (Granted, it's a bit verbose, though.)

You can std::type_identity_t (C++20) and decltype (C++11 keyword) to refer to the anonymous type of the inner member variable.
(Lifted right out of Artyer's comment.)
UPDATE: reading through the question a second time, this answer provides guidance on how to code up the desired behavior, but does not answer the OP's question posed.  User17732522's answer address the language-lawyer aspect of the question.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define STR(x) STR_IMPL(x)
#define STR_IMPL(x) #x

using std::cout;

#if __cpp_lib_type_identity // C++20 feature flag
using std::type_identity_t;
#else
// Fallback for before C++20.
template <class T> struct type_identity { using type = T; };
template <class T> using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
#endif

struct outer {
    struct {
        int x{1000};
        inline int get_x() const;
    } inner;
};

inline int type_identity_t<decltype(outer::inner)>::get_x() const {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    cout << "C++ version " << STR(__cplusplus) << "\n";
    outer o;
    auto x{ o.inner.get_x() };
    cout << "x is " << x << "\n";
}

